# Can I store a Web UserControl ascx and code behind in database and load it from there?

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-user-controls

Is there any way I can store the code of the UserControl in a database table, compile it dynamically or Load it from there ? Means I get a string from database that contains the complete code of UserControl and then add it to the page ?

Comment: @pst Why ? I am currently working on Sharepoint, and it also fetches all its code from database. So, it must be possible somehow.

Comment: It loads user controls from a database...? I was sure they were in ControlTemplates...

Comment: What about the sharepoint master pages ? or the pages that we customize, does they not get saved in the sharepoint database ?

Comment: Those are definitely not. It's been awhile, but all of that should be located in the WSE folder ... somewhere. The URLs are generally the only thing stored in the DB. See http://grounding.co.za/blogs/brett/archive/2008/03/24/sharepoint-get-to-know-the-directory-structure-in-the-12-hive.aspx -- most of the stuff (ASCX, master templates) are under the "TEMPLATE" folder in the "hive" (SP 2010 is "14 hive".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few ideas:

1. Use [UserControl.LoadControl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol.loadcontrol.aspx) with temp files
2. Use UserControl.LoadControl() with HttpHandler
3. Use [BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.buildmanager.createinstancefromvirtualpath.aspx) with entire pages (instead of controls)

**Option 1: temp files (easiest)**

1. Create a directory for your web application to write to, e.g. `~/tmp/` (and give the web application *modify* & *create* permissions to that directory)
2. Save the UserControl contents to a temp file:

   ```
   string userControlContents = /* get user control contents from database */;
   string path = Server.MapPath("~/tmp/2011081612332423.ascx");
   System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, userControlContents);
   ```
3. Load the user control:

   ```
   Control c = UserControl.LoadControl("~/tmp/2011081612332423.ascx")
   ```
4. Add the user control to the desired page:

   ```
   this.Controls.Add(c);
   ```

**Option 2: HttpHandler**

1. Implement a page or HttpHandler that gets the UserControl contents by id and outputs the raw contents from the database to the `Response` stream

   - **This might not work** since UserControl.LoadControl() probably doesn't care about the Response stream.
2. Then load the control as in *Option 1*:

   ```
   Control c = UserControl.LoadControl("~/UserControlFromDB.ascx?id=392")
   ```

   - ASP.NET JIT caching might break since the file name "UserControlFromDB.ascx" is always the same (only `id=NNN` changes). URL rewriting might work around this.

**Option 3: Compiling *pages* instead of just *controls*:**

`BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath()` compiles a `Page` in ASP.NET from a virtual path. So you could store an entire *page* in the database and compile it dynamically.

---

**Disclaimer:** I don't recommend storing controls or pages in the database; it will increase maintenance, debugging, and security costs.